# How to save a photo and a text

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have an image and a text. If the user clicks to the safeButton I would like to save it.

```
@IBOutlet weak var img1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var text1: UITextField!
@IBAction func saveButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    save()
}
```

I could safe the view with the func snapshot. But how can I save the text, the img and the snapshot?

I tried the func save. I have an error in the func save: "use of unresolved identifier Object" "use of unresolved identifier imageView"

```
func save() {
    var object = Object( text: textField.text!, image:
        imageView.image, image: image)
}

func snapshot() -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
    self.view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.view.frame,
        afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let image : UIImage =
    UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way to do it:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var newImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var img1: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func saveIt(sender: AnyObject) {
        //first make an UIImage from your view
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size)
        self.view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        let sourceImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        //draw new Image
        //position the image
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img1.frame.size)
        sourceImage.drawAtPoint(CGPointMake(0, 0))
        let croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        //assign new Image
        newImage.image = croppedImage
    }
}
```

And result will be:

[image]

Comment: I do not understand, what is imageV and newImage? remember that I have an image: img1 and a text: text1

Comment: check this sample project: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=01181130664546476047

Comment: I do not need to draw an new image. What I asked is how to save a text and an image. I could check that my func snapshot works well. My problem is the func save

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways:

1- Saving the photo in a temporary directory. Example:

```
var fileManager = NSFileManager()
var tmpDir = NSTemporaryDirectory()
let filename = "YourImageName.png"
let path = tmpDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(filename)
var error: NSError?
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(YourImageView.image)
fileManager.removeItemAtPath(path, error: nil)
println(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path))

if(imageData.writeToFile(path,atomically: true)){
    println("Image saved.")
}else{
    println("Image not saved.")
}
```

2- Saving using [Photos Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Framework/). Example:

```
if let image: UIImage = YourImageView.image

            let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0), {
                PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
                    let createAssetRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(image)
                    let assetPlaceholder = createAssetRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset
                    if let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(forAssetCollection: self.assetCollection, assets: self.photosAsset) {
                        albumChangeRequest.addAssets([assetPlaceholder])
                    }
                    }, completionHandler: {(success, error)in
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                            NSLog("Adding Image to Library -> %@", (success ? "Sucess":"Error!"))
                        })
                })

            })
        }
```

You can check this [project sample](https://github.com/TDAbboud/PhotosGalleryApp).

Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32015320/3273221